# Convert Long HEX String To HEX bytes array using VB.NET 2015

Tags: vb.net

How to convert Long HEX String value to HEX byte array using VB.Net. Consider If I have `01 H3 HB HD3 H0 HA H36 H10` long hex string, I want to convert it to `&H1, &H3, &HB, &HD3, &H0, &HA, &H36, &H10`.

Then I can `Dim bytes1() As Byte =` to Hex byte array.

I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
Private Function HexStringToBytes(ByVal input As String) As Byte()
    input = input.Trim().ToUpper()
    input = input.Replace("&H", "")
    input = input.Replace(" ", "")

    Dim byteStrings() As String = input.Split(New Char() {","c})
    If (byteStrings.Length > 0) Then
        Dim retVal() As Byte = CType(Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Byte), byteStrings.Length), Byte())
        Dim idx As Integer = 0
        For Each byteString As String In byteStrings
            retVal(idx) = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16)
            idx += 1
        Next
        Return retVal
    End If
    Return New Byte() {}
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but there are two things you need to correct. First, you remove the spaces in the string, making it harder to separate each number:

```
input = input.Replace(" ", "")
```

Secondly, you split by a **comma** (`,`) but your string doesn't have any commas, so it doesn't really do anything:

```
Dim byteStrings() As String = input.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

The solution is quite simple: Remove the `input = input.Replace(" ", "")` line and split by spaces instead:

```
Dim byteStrings() As String = input.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` makes sure that there are no empty strings in the array.

Finally, as a suggestion you can replace:

```
Dim retVal() As Byte = CType(Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Byte), byteStrings.Length), Byte())
```

with either:

```
Dim retVal() As Byte = New Byte(byteStrings.Length - 1) {}
```

or:

```
Dim retVal(byteStrings.Length - 1) As Byte
```

Comment: It says Could not find any recognizable digits. retVal(idx) = Convert.ToByte(byteString, 16) line

Comment: @sajiindra : Your input text seems to be missing `&H` in front of every number and uses just `H`. Either add a `&` in your other code, or add this to your current method: `input = input.Replace("H", "")`

Comment: @sajiindra : That is a completely different question, I don't see how that is related to your first issue. If you have another problem please ask a new question instead.

Comment: As for extracting a certain amount of characters, just use [**`String.Substring()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: I posted a new question please find it out. The first question to get HEX array that is related to the second question that array goes to HEX to decimal convert.

Comment: @sajiindra : Will do, but if my answer helped you solve _this_ problem please mark it as accepted.